# Why does any row I insert into my AWS Postgres database (with psycopg2) immediately become a dead tuple?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-rds, psycopg2, pgadmin

Having a problem with connecting psycopg2 to an AWS Postgres server and inserting a row.
Below is a test script that attempts to connect to the server and insert one row. The test query works when I use it in pgAdmin. That is, it runs successfully and the row can be selected.

When I run the python script, the server shows that a connection is made. No exceptions are thrown. I can even try to insert like a hundred rows and there's a big spike in traffic. And yet nothing can be found in the table.

```
import psycopg2
from getpass import getpass
​
# connect to database
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname    = "postgres",
        user      = "username",
        password  = getpass(),
        host      = "blahblah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
        port      = '5432'
    )
    print("connected!")
except:
    print("oops")
​
#cursor object
cursor_boi = connection.cursor()
​
# simple test query
test_query = """INSERT INTO reviews (review_id, username, movie_id, review_date, review_text, review_title, user_rating, helpful_num, helpful_denom) 
VALUES (1, 'myname', 12345678, '2016-06-23', 'I love this movie!', 'Me happy', 5, 6, 12 )"""
​
# execute query
try:
    cursor_boi.execute(test_query)
    print(test_query)
except:
    print("oopsie!")
​
# close connection
if(connection):
    cursor_boi.close()
    connection.close()
```

The database statistics report the following for my "reviews" table:

**Tuples inserted: 257**

**Tuples deleted: 1**

**Dead Tuples: 8**

**Last autovacuum:  2019-12-13 15:49:20.369715+00**

And the Dead Tuples field increments every time I run the Python script. So it seems that every record I insert immediately becomes a dead tuple. Why is this, and how can I stop it? I imagine the records are being overwritten, but if so, they're not being replaced with anything.

Comment: Because you don't `connection.commit()` the changes. You just close the connection.

Comment: @roganjosh I just now thought of that and added `connection.commit()` just before `cursor_boi.close()`. But it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Wait, it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my postgresql function insert rolling back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224231/why-is-my-postgresql-function-insert-rolling-back)

Comment: @richyen given the the question, discussion, and the posted answer, why would you think that was at all relevant as a dupe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I forgot to commit the connection with `connection.commit()`. Thanks @roganjosh.